# Start and stop audio streaming using http or mqtt calls - Python

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, pyaudio

I have a python script that streams audio. It uses websockets, asyncio and pyaudio. I want to start and stop streaming or this complete script with HTTP or MQTT call. Currently what I am doing manually i.e.
To Start : python script.py
To Stop : Ctrl C

What approach shall I use?

```
# starts recording
stream = p.open(
   format=FORMAT,
   channels=CHANNELS,
   rate=RATE,
   input=True,
   frames_per_buffer=FRAMES_PER_BUFFER
)

async def send_receive():
   print(f'Connecting websocket to url ${URL}')
   async with websockets.connect(
       URL,
       extra_headers=(("Authorization", auth_key),),
       ping_interval=5,
       ping_timeout=20
   ) as _ws:
       await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
       print("Receiving SessionBegins ...")
       session_begins = await _ws.recv()
       print(session_begins)
       print("Sending messages ...")
       async def send():
           while True:
               try:
                   data = stream.read(FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)
                   data = base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf-8")
                   json_data = json.dumps({"audio_data":str(data)})
                   await _ws.send(json_data)
               except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError as e:
                   print(e)
                   assert e.code == 4008
                   break
               except Exception as e:
                   assert False, "Not a websocket 4008 error"
               await asyncio.sleep(0.01)

           return True

       async def receive():
           while True:
               try:
                   result_str = await _ws.recv()
                   print(json.loads(result_str)['text'])
               except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError as e:
                   print(e)
                   assert e.code == 4008
                   break
               except Exception as e:
                   assert False, "Not a websocket 4008 error"

       send_result, receive_result = await asyncio.gather(send(), receive())


asyncio.run(send_receive())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start and stop a Python script using an HTTP call, you can set up a web server that listens for specific requests to trigger the execution or termination of your script. Here's a basic example using the Flask framework:

Install Flask:

```
pip install flask
```

Create a new Python file, e.g., script_controller.py, and import the necessary modules:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)
process = None
```

Define route handlers for starting and stopping the script:

```
@app.route('/start_script', methods=['POST'])
def start_script():
    global process
    if process is None or process.poll() is not None:
        # Start the script if it's not already running
        process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'your_script.py'])
        return 'Script started successfully.'
    else:
        return 'Script is already running.'

@app.route('/stop_script', methods=['POST'])
def stop_script():
    global process
    if process and process.poll() is None:
        # Terminate the script if it's running
        process.terminate()
        return 'Script stopped successfully.'
    else:
        return 'Script is not running.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Replace 'your_script.py' in the start_script route handler with the filename of the script you want to execute.

Start the web server by running the script_controller.py file:

```
python script_controller.py
```

Once the server is running, you can send HTTP requests to start or stop the script:

To start the script:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/start_script
```

To stop the script:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/stop_script
```

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies here since your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.